# which.min() with random sampling

Tags: r

I have a vector of variables:

```
x<-runif(1000,0,1)
```

I would like to select the element with the lowest value:

`x[which.min(x)]`

By default `which.min(x)` will return the first element that satisfies this condition, however, it can happen that there are multiple elements that are equally low.

is there a way to sample from those values and return only one ?

Comment: But if they are all the same why do you care which one is returned?

Comment: @SimonO101, I guess it's that `which.min` returns the position, not the value?

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for (hopefully) clearing that up, I've added an answer if that is the case.

Comment: you may want to have a look at the [nnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html) package as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which` to find the indices of all those elements which are equal to the minimum of the vector and randomly sample one (unless the minimum value appears once - then we can just return it).

```
# Find indices of minima of vector
ids <- which( x == min(x) )

#  If the minimum value appear multiple times pick one index at random otherwise just return its position in the vector
if( length( ids ) > 1 )
  ids <- sample( ids , 1 )

#  You can use 'ids' to subset as per usual
x[ids]
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same, but you need to work on this. Remember what `sample` does when you sample from a single number (eg `sample(300, 1)`.

Comment: As usual:  `x==min(x)` is not safe for floats. `abs(x-min(x)) < tiny_value` is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar approach, but one which does not use `if` is to do a `sample` with `seq_along` the matched values.

Here are two examples. `x1` has multiple min values. `x2` has just one.

```
## Make some sample data
set.seed(1)
x1 <- x2 <- sample(100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
x2[x2 == 1][-1] <- 2 ## Make x2 have just one min value

## Identify the minimum values, and extract just one of them.
y <- which(x1 == min(x1))
y[sample(seq_along(y), 1)]
# [1] 721

z <- which(x2 == min(x2))
z[sample(seq_along(z), 1)]
# [1] 463
```